# Adding a new field in Firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

In firestore, a field is like a column in mysql.  How can I add a field in every existing document in Firestore using Javascript?

I am interested to add an empty array field in every document.

I thought this is common but somehow I could not find any relevant info.

```
 const firebase = require("firebase");

 require("firebase/firestore");

firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "XXXX",
  authDomain: "xxxx",
  projectId: "xxxx"
});

var db = firebase.firestore();

function getMyDocs() {
   const snapshot = 
 firebase.firestore().collection('testusers').get()
  return snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
    db.collection("testusers").doc(doc.id).update({
        title: "Testing"
    })
  });
 };

 getMyDocs();
```

This is a nodejs code but I am getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: please add your codes to help u.

Comment: Mine is a flutter app, but I am looking for Javascript code to add a field to Firestore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fetch all docs and update each one seperatly.

JS Code:

```
async getMyDocs() {
    const snapshot = await db.collection('myCollection').get()
    return snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
      db.collection("myCollection").doc(doc.id).update({myNewField:"fieldValue"})
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, but I am getting error.  Can you help me to take a look at my code in the question?

Comment: @DarylWong I updated it, pls try and pls don't remove async and await

Comment: Kamuran, getting this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

Firestore is nosql.There are no columns or rows.
Instead, you store data in documents, which are organized into collections.
Each document contains a set of key-value pairs. The structure is dynamic.
You can think it like a big json object.